# Python Altair Vega chart not displaying

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, altair

I have the following code snippet:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

alt.renderers.enable('default')

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('CCCDDDEEE'),
                     'b': [2, 7, 4, 1, 2, 6, 8, 4, 7]})

chart = alt.Chart(data)

alt.Chart(data).mark_point().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
)
```

I have installed Altair and Vega and Notebook already:

`Altair` version: 4.1.0

`Notebook` version: 6.4.0

`Vega` version: 3.5.0

`Python` version: 3.7.8

`http://localhost:8889/tree#notebooks` is open in a tab.

When I run my `Python` program, nothing happens.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the enable line to just after importing altair, e.g.

```
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('default')
```

then restarting the kernel and re-running. That seems to work for me.

Comment: Thank you Matt. What do I do to restart the kernel? I don't know what that means...

Comment: Restarting the kernel essentially closes and restarts the underlying instance of ipython that is running in the notebook. So, it clears out the memory and any imported modules, so that things start fresh. In the Jupyter notebook there should be a tab in the task bar called "Kernel", and if you click on that you can select "Restart" in the drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I edited my post and added an image of my Jupyter UI. I do not have the options you are describing...

Comment: It looks like you've got the Google Chrome "Developer tools" open on the right half of your browser (did you press Ctrl+ Shft + I?). Close that down (with the cross in the upper right) and open the file with the "ipynb" extension that contains the Python code that you were running. When you have that open you should see the "Kernel" tab.

Comment: oh I see! OK, I did that. I added an image that shows the result...

Comment: Where were your running the code originally if it wasn't in the Jupyter notebook? Were you running in an anaconda/conda virtual environment in which you'd installed altair? The error message is showing that the Jupyter notebook has be opened in an environment that doesn't have altair installed. The simplest option is to try running `!pip install altair` in one of the notebook cells.

Comment: I installed Altair via pip and opened PyCharm to write the code and then opened Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda3) via the Start menu (which launched a new browser tab at `http://localhost:8889/tree#notebooks`) and then ran the Python script in PyCharm. I expected to see the chart on that page/tab. Do I need to do all this in a virtual environment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235131/discussion-between-matt-pitkin-and-catarinaruna).